# Ipython - Notebook error: Tornado.application : "Module" object has no attribute 'XREQ'

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am using python 2.6, ipython 0.12.1, tornado 3.02, pyzmq 13.1 , I am getting this error when I start ipython notebook. 
"Websocket connection cannot be made" 
In the ipython console window I get torado.application error , in line 183 in create_shell_stream
shell_stream = self.create_connected_stream(ip.....,zmq.XREQ)
error is "module" object has no attribute 'XREQ'

Do you know what's wrong? and how can I fix this error?
I installed ipython, tornado and pyzmq seperate and not from easy_install or pip.

Answer (score 1):

For those who end up on this page, here's the solution. This is happening because your OS package manager (in my case 12.04) is lagging pypi in python packages - but not in core libraries (like zeromq).

To solve this, my recommended solution is to install python-pandas using your package manager, but also install systemwide "pip". and then run "sudo pip install --upgrade ipython,pandas"
this should get everything back in sync.